# How to can I create an array of knockout.js observables?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0, knockout-mvc

I have an array of objects for which I am showing their properties.
How can add an individual edit functionality to them? Lets say it to be an edit button for each one of the elements of the list.

I want to show input fields instead of text fields when the object is in edit mode, for this I am using the visible binding. So I need a Boolean observable for each of them.

How can I do this without knowing the amount of elements in the list... I also have add and delete, so I would need to add more observables to this array each time a new element is created.

I also tried to give a ko.observable element to my objects but I could not do this.

Comment: In this link, http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html, in the 'Note 5: Dynamically choosing which template is used', there is an idea to resolver your problem.  Two templates, one for the edit mode, other for the read mode.  Other option is to use the 'if' binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @JoseLuis , I'll read about the templates! But can you tell me more about how you'd it with the 'if' binding.

Comment: This link (http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html) answers your question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I like to use an object inside the `observableArray`. Here is an example of an inline edit feature for as many many rows as needed.

```js
function Employee(emp) {
  var self = this;
  self.Name = ko.observable(emp.Name);
  self.Age = ko.observable(emp.Age);
  self.Salary = ko.observable(emp.Salary);
  self.EditMode = ko.observable(emp.EditMode);
  self.ChangeMode = function() {
    self.EditMode(!self.EditMode());
  }
}

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.Employees = ko.observableArray()
  self.Employees.push(new Employee({
    Name: "Joe",
    Age: 20,
    Salary: 100,
    EditMode: false
  }));

  self.Employees.push(new Employee({
    Name: "Steve",
    Age: 22,
    Salary: 121,
    EditMode: false
  }));

  self.Employees.push(new Employee({
    Name: "Tom",
    Age: 24,
    Salary: 110,
    EditMode: false
  }));
}
var VM = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(VM);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees">
    <tr data-bind="if: !EditMode()">
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Age"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Salary"></td>
      <td><button data-bind="click: ChangeMode">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="if: EditMode()">
      <td>
        <input data-bind="value: Name">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-bind="value: Age">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input data-bind="value: Salary">
      </td>
      <td><button data-bind="click:ChangeMode">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Very useful, I was able to do the edit as I said, but after this I need to convert my objects to JSON (and obviously without the EditMode variable), is there a way to do so? I tried to do:
`var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(self.editedResources());`
But it says: Unable to get property 'toJS' of undefined or null reference.
....self.editedResources ys my observable array

Comment: @DiegoAstiazarán It's `ko.toJS()` or `ko.toJSON()` you can use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to get rid of the property once in js/json