# KnockoutJs single editable row in datagrid

Tags: c#, typescript, knockout.js, datagrid, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create an editable datagrid. I would like to click on the Edit button to edit only the given line. But I will end with all lines being editable. I created two templats. One for displaying and one for editing:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Capacity</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="room" data-bind="template: {name: selectedTemplate, foreach: roomList}"></tbody>
    </table>

    @*Templates*@
    <script type="text/html" id="baseTemplate">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: capacity"></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" data-bind="click: function() { $root.edit($data) }">Edit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>

    <script type="text/html" id="editTemplate">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $root._id"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: $root._number" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: $root._capacity" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" data-bind="click: function() {$root.update($data)}">Update</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>
```

ViewModel in TypeScript:

```
import * as ko from 'knockout';
import { RoomDTO } from "./../DTO/roomDTO";

class RoomIndexVM {
    roomList: KnockoutObservableArray<RoomDTO>;
    selectedTemplate: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    _id: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    _number: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    _capacity: KnockoutObservable<number>;

    constructor() {
        this.roomList = ko.observableArray();
        this.selectedTemplate = ko.observable("baseTemplate");

        this._id = ko.observable();
        this._number = ko.observable();
        this._capacity = ko.observable();
    }

    private getAllRooms() {
        return new Promise<Array<RoomDTO>>((resolve) => {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: `/api/room/getall?skip=${0}&take=${0}`
            }).done((result: Array<RoomDTO>) => {
                resolve(result);
            }).fail(function (ex) {
                console.log(`Error: ${ex}`);
            });
        });
    }

    private updateRoom(data: RoomDTO) {
        return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                url: `/api/room/update`
            }).done((result: number) => {
                resolve(result);
            }).fail(function (ex) {
                console.log(`Error: ${ex}`);
            });
        });
    }

    private updateRoomList(result: Array<RoomDTO>) {
        this.roomList.removeAll();

        result.forEach((value, index) => {
            this.roomList.push(value);
        });
    }

    public changeTemplate(template: string) {
        switch (template) {
            case "base":
                this.selectedTemplate("baseTemplate");
                break;
            case "edit":
                this.selectedTemplate("editTemplate");
            default:
        }
    }

    public async edit(room: RoomDTO) {
        this.changeTemplate('edit');
    }

    public async update(room: RoomDTO) {
        alert("in edit");
        this.changeTemplate("base");
        console.log(await this.updateRoom(room));
        this.updateRoomList(await this.getAllRooms());
    }

    public async initialize() {
        this.updateRoomList(await this.getAllRooms());
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    let roomIndexVM = new RoomIndexVM();
    ko.applyBindings(roomIndexVM);

    roomIndexVM.initialize();
}
```

This is the result when I switch templats:
[image]

How can I make editable only one row?

Comment: Please share the js too.

Comment: ViewModel in TypeScript added.

Comment: I used a similar idea for an answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44762959/7314155) question. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Since you share the template name with all the list items, editing one changes the template for everyone.

the solution is to make a separate observable property for every list item

Comment: I'm sorry but I still do not know how to do it. I created a separate properties in a viewmodel and used it for template values. But it still does not work.